# Loading ajax JSON failure

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

the bellow scripts runs at my Local Host but does not work at my Site.
I'm just testing simple Json script in jqueryMobile list format
any idea what is wrong??

thanks

HTML page click to call Ajax function:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" /> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="protected/jQuery/jquery.mobile.structure-1.0.1.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="protected/themes/Green/red_theme.min.css" />
<script src="news_services/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="news_services/js/jquery.mobile-1.0rc1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="protected/jsnM.js"> </script>
</head>
<body >
<div data-role="page" id="home" >
    <div data-role="header" >
        <h1>JSON testing</h1>
        <div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal"></div>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <p> Json testing</p>
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer">
        <a href="#getAll_JSON" onClick="jsn1()" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-icon="info">call JSON</a>
    </div>
</div>
<div data-role="page" id="getAll_JSON">
    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" >
        <h1>Json format</h1>
        <div data-type="horizontal" >
            <a href="#home" data-role="button"  data-inline="true" data-icon="home">Home</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <ul id="sitesList" data-role="listview" data-filter="true" data-split-icon="gear" >
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed"></div>
</div>
<div id="detailsPage" data-role="page" >
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>info</h1>
        <div data-type="horizontal" >
            <a href="#home" data-role="button"  data-inline="true" data-icon="home">Home</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <div id="sitesDetail" >
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

call Ajax here:

```
var areaID=0;

function jsn1(val)
{   
var url_Category="http://gonorth.co.il/protected/indexJSON.php?";

$.ajax({
    url: url_Category,
    type: "GET",
    data: 'No='+val+"&area="+areaID,
    dataType: "json",
    cache: false, 
    error: function () {
        alert('loading Ajax failure');
        } ,
    onFailure: function () {
        alert('Ajax Failure');
    } ,
     statusCode: {
        404: function() {
            alert("missing info");
        }   
    },
    success: function(result) {
            $('#sitesList li').remove();
        $.each(result.sites,function(index,dat){
            $("#sitesList").append(
                '<li>'+
                '<img src="images/'+dat.coupon_img+'" width=80/>' +
                '<p >Name: '+dat.coupon_name+'</p>'+
                '<p >info: '+dat.street+'</p>'+
                '<p >address:'+dat.coupon_tmp+'</p>'+
                '</li>'
            );
        });

        $('#sitesList').listview('refresh');        
    }
});
}
```

PHP results:

```
<?php
    $arr = array();
        $arr[] =[
                "coupon_id" => '1',
                "coupon_img" => '1.jpg',
                "street" => 'long text', 
                "coupon_tmp" => 'Address', 
                "coupon_name" => 'Name'
                ];
echo '{"sites":'.json_encode($arr).'}';
?>
```

Comment: Does is not work in some special way?

Comment: are there any error messages thrown in the console of your browser? Ist the html located on the same domain as the JSON resource (you could run into cross domain issues).

Comment: the error message is the Ajax error: function () {
        alert('loading Ajax failure');

Comment: the Ajax runs from the same domain

Answer (score 0):

When I visit this link: http://gonorth.co.il/protected/indexJSON.php, it looks like your JSON is being served through a PHP parser by your web server. You should look into your web server's settings and find out how to set it up in such a way that JSON files will be served with a content-type of `application/json`. The current response comes down with a conten-type of `text/html`, which is most likely because it's trying to be parsed by a PHP parser and the parser chokes on the syntax, or something like that, and the server then renders a html error page.

Comment: Do you think it is wrong PHP jSON encoding. could be something wrong in the syntax: echo '{"sites":'.json_encode($arr).'}';

Comment: I don't think it is 'web server settings' problem because I'm runing JSON in jQuery and it is working fine, something is wrong with my Ajax settings I'm sure

Comment: Im not sure mate, I don't know much about PHP syntax, all I'm seeing is that it looks like something to do with PHP is not being able to parse the JSON. One thing that is for sure is that if your server throws an error, it has probably not much to do with your AJAX setting in jQuery. I'd say you should play with settings on your webserver or your server side PHP code until at least the link returns some valid JSON with the right content-type, then see if your client side is able to read or retrieve it.

Comment: how can I see the return server content-type??

Comment: I add header to the PHP - content-type of application/json

Comment: Hi I found that some how PHP sent the Array [ sign, I changed the Array format and it seams the JSON value's correct but now the JSON objects came with "Undefined"  - any idea??

Comment: It seems you are trying to loop over a collection of sites, if I go to your [link](http://gonorth.co.il/protected/indexJSON.php) it doesn't look like it returns a collection, but that could off course be different for you since you are adding something extra to the query string. It's hard to say what's wrong without seeing the exact JSON which is being returned to you. If it is similar to what I am seeing on that link, then `result.sites`, which you are looping over in your success function, is going to be `undefined`. But `result.coupon_id` would give me `1`.

Answer (score 0):

thanks to all the answers.
the problem, was Php array
probably different Php versions in my Loclahost and serevr
the next Php Array workedd in my LocalHost but didn;t worked in the server

```
<?php
$arr = array();
    $arr[] =[
            "coupon_id" => '1',
            "coupon_img" => '1.jpg',
            "street" => 'long text', 
            "coupon_tmp" => 'Address', 
            "coupon_name" => 'Name'
            ];
echo '{"sites":'.json_encode($arr).'}';
?>
```

I changed it to

```
<?php
    $arr[] =array(
            "coupon_id" => '1',
            "coupon_img" => '1.jpg',
            "street" => 'long text', 
            "coupon_tmp" => 'Address', 
            "coupon_name" => 'Name'
            );
echo '{"sites":'.json_encode($arr).'}';
?>
```

and it worked in the server as well

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $arr = array();
        $arr[] =[
                "coupon_id" => '1',
                "coupon_img" => '1.jpg',
                "street" => 'long text', 
                "coupon_tmp" => 'Address', 
                "coupon_name" => 'Name'
                ];
        $res['sites']=$arr;
        echo json_encode($res);
?>
```